# Excel VBA macro to match spreadsheet value with sql server table

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, macros

I've macro that takes the cell value from excel column A and checks that value in the sql server db and returns the data on the spreadsheet. Now I need to match two columns from the spreadsheet column A and column B and if the condition is true return all the data on the spreadsheet. My macro works fine with single condition (for Column A) but when I edit my SQL statement in the macro to include second condition (for column F) I get an error message

> Runtime error 2147217913 800040e07.

Here is my macro:

```
Sub GetSQLData()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim newrow As String


'MODIFIED: create the search string for the IN-Statement
newrow = "("
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    newrow = newrow & "'" & Left(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value), 7) & "',"

Next i

newrow2 = "("
For j = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
   newrow2 = newrow2 & "'" & Left(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "F").Value), 7) & "',"

Next j


'QueryDatabase:
newrow = Left(newrow, Len(newrow) - 1)
newrow = newrow & ")"

newrow2 = Left(newrow2, Len(newrow2) - 1)
newrow2 = newrow2 & ")"

' Create the connection string.
 sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=0.0.0.0;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=Shipment;" & _
                  "User ID=Temp;Password=test123;"



' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT 'Message' = Case When s.ShipmentID is not Null Then 'Error: Already Loaded' When IsNull(j.Invoice_Number, 0) <> 0 Then 'Error: Already Invoiced' Else 'Ready to Upload' End,convert(varchar(10), s.[ShipDate], 120)'Ship_date', j.[num2],j.[customer], s.[ShipPickUpCompany], s.[ShipPickUpCity],s.[ShipPickUpState],s.[ShipDeliveryCompany],s.[ShipDeliveryCity],s.[ShipDeliveryState],'Service' = 'Truck',s.[ShipCost],s.[ShipType], s.[Shipqty], 'Tracking' = LTRIM(RTRIM(Convert(Char(10), s.[ShipDate], 101))) + ' - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(convert(Char(10),s.[Shipqty],101)))+ ' - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(j.[Project_description])), s.[ShipPaid], S.[ShipReasonPaid], isnull(s.[ShipPrice],'')'ShipPrice' , s.[ShipHandlingPrice],j.Invoice_Number, case when isnull(j.Invoice_Number,'') = 0 then 'NotInvoiced' else 'Invoiced' end 'InvoiceStatus' FROM [shipment].[dbo].[num_tab] j left join [shipment].[dbo].[Tracking] s on s.ShipNum = j.num2 " & _
                       "where j.[num2] IN " & Trim(newrow) & " AND S.[Shipqty] IN " & Trim(newrow2) & "  ")


' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.

        'Sheets(1).Cells("B1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
           For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For j = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
              Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:AD1") = Array("Message", "ShipDate", "JobNumber", "Customer", "FromCompany", "FromCity", "FromState", "ToCompany", "ToCity", "ToState", "ShipService", "ShipCost", "Type(F,P,S,R)", "Quantity", "TrackingNumber", "Paid(Y,N)?", "PaidReason(C,E,M,F,P)", "ShipPrice", "HandlingPrice", "Invoice_Number", "InvoiceStatus")

             If Trim(rs("num2").Value) = Left(Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value), 7) And Trim(rs("shipqty").Value) = Left(Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(j, "F").Value), 7) Then
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "J").Value = rs("Message").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "K").Value = rs("Ship_Date").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "L").Value = rs("num2").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "M").Value = rs("customer").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "N").Value = rs("ShipPickUpCompany").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "O").Value = rs("ShipPickUpCity").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "P").Value = rs("ShipPickUpState").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "Q").Value = rs("ShipDeliveryCompany").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "R").Value = rs("ShipDeliveryCity").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "S").Value = rs("ShipDeliveryState").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "T").Value = rs("Service").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "U").Value = rs("ShipCost").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "V").Value = rs("ShipType").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "W").Value = rs("Shipqty").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "X").Value = rs("Tracking").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "Y").Value = rs("ShipPaid").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "Z").Value = rs("ShipReasonPaid").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "AA").Value = rs("ShipPrice").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "AB").Value = rs("ShipHandlingPrice").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "AC").Value = rs("Invoice_Number").Value
                                Sheets(1).Cells(i, "AD").Value = rs("InvoiceStatus").Value

                             End If
             Next j
            Next i

        rs.MoveNext
        Loop




' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical

End If

' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which command produces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web search would have given you the answer in the very first result. You're getting a data-type mismatch error. This is likely because your column F has values you're not expecting. You can check this by doing a `debug.print` of your SELECT statement.

You seem to be comparing your newrow and newrow2 against numerical values like shipping quantity (this is a guess based on the column names). If so, you might want to reconsider putting single quotes around each of the values you're adding into newrow and newrow2.

Can you check the error: is it 80040e07 or 800040e07 as you posted?